# Date error in android to store in sqlite

Tags: java, android

I am trying to in insert date into sqlite using:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String data = format.format(new Date(19900101));
System.err.println("Time is.."+format.format(19900101));
```

But i am getting 19700101 in log. i am getting same result even if i change the dates as 20000101 or any thing.

Any one suggest me why it happens?

Answer (score 4):

the code is wrong

```
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
      Date data = format.parse("19900101");
      System.out.println("Time is.."+data );
```

when u use new Date(123) it expects some time in milliseconds i think

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as for formatting current string to date :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

Date convertedDate = (Date) format.parse("19900101");

SimpleDateFormat formats = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String fmconvertedDate =formats.format(convertedDate);

System.err.println("Time is.."+fmconvertedDate);
```

and output is :

```
Time is..1990-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: getting result as unparsble date @prosper k

Comment: @alex : i have tested this code in my side and working perfectly

Comment: @alex : it's printing `Time is..Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 1990` in log

Comment: i just need 1990-01-01 00:00:00 @prosper

Comment: @alex : means you are trying to do this using sql package ? if we are using SimpleDateFormat then always import java.util.date